# #RubyOnRails Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried run "bundle update" in one project, but the console gives me the next error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
>    In Gemfile:
>      sprockets (= 2.2.2)
>
> rails (= 3.2.8) was resolved to 3.2.8, which depends on
>        actionpack (= 3.2.8) was resolved to 3.2.8, which depends on
>          sprockets (~> 2.1.3)

my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'liquid'
#gem 'RedCloth'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem "rmagick"
gem 'carrierwave'
#gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'simple-private-messages', '0.0.0', :git =>             'git://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages.git'
gem 'rb_wunderground'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'sprockets', '2.2.2' 
gem "jquery-rails"

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  #gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
  #gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more     supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'wicked_pdf'
  gem 'roadie'
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
end
#group :development do
#  gem 'sunspot_solr'
#end

#gem "progress_bar"
gem "declarative_authorization"
gem 'jquery-rails'
#gem 'tire'
#gem 'rsolr'
#gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'texticle', require: 'texticle/rails'
gem "recaptcha", :require => "recaptcha/rails"
gem 'kaminari'


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'rails-i18n'

gem 'kaminari-i18n'

gem 'constantcontact'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'table_print'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  gem "declarative_authorization"
end

 gem 'paperclip'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'textacular'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to not specify the exact sprockets version. For example :

```
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `gem 'sprockets', '2.2.2'` with gem `'sprockets', '~> 3.7.1'`. That's a change to the syntax and the version.  You can check the current version of gems at [RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/sprockets/versions/3.5.2)